# Double integral on an intersection of two parallel cylinders

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Take the cylinders $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (centered at $(0,0)$) and $x^2 +y^2 = 2y \Rightarrow x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ (centered at $(0,1)$). I plot both cylinders.
[image]
My problem is to calculate the integral
$$ \iint_D (x^2 + y^2) \ dxdy ,$$
where $$D = \lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 <1, x^2 + (y-1)^2 >1 , x \geq 0 \rbrace$$
I guess cylindrical coordinates will be useful here. How can I express de region $D$ in these coordinates $(\rho , \theta , z)$ where $z=z$, $x = \rho \cos \theta$ and $y = \rho \sin \theta$?
I know that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ reads as $\rho = 1$ and $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$ reads as $\rho = 2\sin \theta$. But now what? Is it the $z$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Since $x\geq 0$ i think that $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi ]$. Am I right? What about $\rho$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey I added the diagram to the question. Let me know if it is correct.

Comment: Where does $z$ enter the problem?  I only see a double integral with $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Paul Nothing is in terms of $z$, right? That's why he just set $z=z$.

Comment: @Gordon, it seems that way, so it's a planar integral in polar coordinates then

Answer (score 0):

Represent the area in polar coordinates as $D_1-D_2$, where $D_1: 0\le \rho \le 1; -\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$

$D_2: 0 \le \rho \le \sin \theta; 0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$